# How to input this format of high order derivative by hand?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

For example,when I input `D[y[x],{x,3}]`,it gives me [image],and its fullform is `Derivative[3][y][x]`,but when I try to input `y^(3)[x]`by hand,its fullform is`Power[y,3][x]`.How can I make it mean a derivative instead of a power.

Comment: Why not just enter the `FullForm`?

Answer (score 8):

By inspecting the box structure of the output of `Derivative[3][y][x]`, we can define an input alias for this type of notation:

```
<< Notation`
AddInputAlias["dn" -> ParsedBoxWrapper[
   RowBox[{
     SuperscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", 
      TagBox[RowBox[{"(", "\[Placeholder]", ")"}], Derivative], 
      MultilineFunction -> None],
     "[", "\[Placeholder]", "]"
     }]]
]
```

You can now use this by typing `ESC dn ESC` and then fill in the placeholders (you can use tab to move to the next placeholder).